# Does the Angular CLI support code releases and maintenance?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

The new Angular CLI is great for quickly setting up and scaffolding an Angular project. Will it also help with code updates and maintenance for future Angular releases? I am planning for maintenance of our code base with future Angular versions, such as described in the official roadmap:

http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/10/versioning-and-releasing-angular.html

Answer (score 0):

The Angular CLI offers some update functionality (dependencies as far as I know) with [`ng update`](https://angular.io/cli/update), but it cannot perform the maintenance tasks of the application. They do provide manual steps to assist in listing the simple steps it should take to upgrade your application at the [Update Angular](https://update.angular.io/) site. It's also possible to use [`schematics`](https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2) to update code as well (which is what I recommend for a longer project).